# Any resources for how to read image files

Tags: opengl, c++, image-processing

I'm learning opengl and I'm the kinda guy who likes to write things from scratch and I was searching for how I can read image files data to create my own image importing library to use for textures but I couldn't find anything useful except reading a bmp file. Can you recommend any resources that might help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the 'file format'. This is the fancy name you will have to search for when looking up the byte protocols for a file.

For BMP, you can find the info you want [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). This is probably denser than you might be used to, so if you want something that you can directly read from then [this stack overflow post might be nicer for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure).

If you want to get good practice without using any of the above, [this](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm) might be a great site to practice from since it gives you the higher level stuff for bitmap files succinctly and describes it effectively.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate all these informations. For the bmp files I have managed to import them, I was talking about other types than bmp like png or jpeg and thank you again I would upvote but I have to have 15 reputation points sorry.

Comment: @Tomahawk png would probably require a library since I recall there being zlib compression. It probably is a much larger challenge than bmp files, and you're best of using a library (but read the file format anyways!) since my guess is that it'd take you a non-trivial amount of time to handle png files.